# My iPhone keeps telling me my cellular data is off?

Tags: wifi, iphone, cellular-data

I have an iPhone 6 and I haven't used cellular data, only Wi-Fi. And every night, only at night while I'm browsing, that tab or whatever it is called keeps popping up and saying that my cellular data is off. I don't understand why do I need to know that multiple times and after appearing a couple of times it turns my Wi-Fi off!

I don't know what to do. It's really annoying.. Some people said to turn off Bluetooth or something with the chip, I don't know, but my Bluetooth is never on because it wastes my battery for nothing. Not sure what to do, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has some information up at:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201673

It basically points you to contact the vendor (i.e. your cellular carrier) to troubleshoot problems with cellular data. Apple would help you locate the cellular data on/off switch in settings, but once you've done that - you could back up your phone and erase it / restore a known good OS and re-test cellular data.

That would let you know it's not software or settings. Then you would need to determine if your phone needed a hardware repair (less likely but possible) or if your carrier can tell why the coverage is spotty or not continuos. They have the cell tower logs and know how your account is set up (as opposed to Apple that designed the device to work with hundreds of carriers).